# Rails 4 saving fields in a similar manner to wordpress options table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to achieve the following scenario. Basically I have 2 models

Theme

- title

Option

- theme_id
- name
- value

In my form I'm trying to let the user populate the Options table with set options, for example my html.erb would possibly look like this:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @options],:class => 'form'  do |f| %>

<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :option[:color] %>
<%= f.text_field :option[:color], :class => 'form-control' %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :option[:header_title] %>
<%= f.text_field :option[:header_title], :class => 'form-control' %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :option[:footer_copy] %>
<%= f.text_field :option[:footer_copy], :class => 'form-control' %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<%= f.submit :value => 'Update', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

The above scenario will add 3 rows to the options table, each with the same theme_id.

But I'm unsure of the syntax to use for the controller (get and post actions), model and view

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks

EDIT
When the above form example is saved it will save as 3 seperate rows in the options table for eg:

theme_id | name | value

1 | "color" | "green"

1 | "header_title" | "Theme title goes here"

1 | "footer_copy" | "lorem ipsum bla bla"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate these fields dynamically on the client side

```
class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :options

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, allow_destroy: true
end
```

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :theme
end
```

```
class ThemesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @theme = Theme.new
    3.times { @theme.options.build }
  end

private
  def theme_params
    params.require(:theme).permit(:title, options_attributes: [:id, :name, :value, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

in your views/themes/_form.html.erb add

```
<%= form_for(@theme) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :options do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'option_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add", f, :options %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

create a new partials views/themes/_option_fields.html.erb

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.select :name, [["Color", "color"], ["Header", "header_title"], ["Footer", "footer_copy"]] %>
  <%= f.text_field :value, placeholder: "Value" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>

  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

in your themes.coffee file add

```
$(document).on "ready page:load", ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
    event.preventDefault()

  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

in application_helper.rb add

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When I built a project similar to this, `Options` had it's own controller with CRUD functionality.

The Video model:

```
theme.rb

has_many :options
```

The Option Model

```
option.rb
belongs_to :video
```

Options Controller:

```
def create
@option = Option.new(option_params)
@video.theme_id = @theme.id
if @option.save
    ...
end
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Drew. This seems to be for a single entry into the Options table though? I'm looking for something where 1 form can add multiple entries into the options table

Comment: The way I read it, it looked like you could have an Options model with Color, Header Title, and Footer as fields. Are you trying to keep all of these items separated?

Comment: Yep, so the options table will just have the fields : theme_id, name, value. I've edited my original question to give an example of how it would be saved in the Options table

Answer (score 1):

You can use fields_for with a themes resource, controller and view, as follows:

```
# routes.rb
resources :themes

# app/controllers/themes_controller.rb
def new
  @theme = Theme.new
end

def create
 @theme = Theme.new theme_params
 @theme.save!

 [:color, :header_title, :footer_copy].each do |option_name|
   theme.options.create! name: option_name, value: params[:theme][option_name]
 end  
end

private
def theme_params
  params.require(:theme).permit(:title)
end

#app/views/themes/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @theme do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <% [:color, :header_title, :footer_copy].each do |option_name|
    <%= f.fields_for option_name do |option_form| %>
      <div>
        <%= option_form.label option_name %>
        <%= option_form.text_field option_name %>
      </div>  
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You may add error checking, styling, etc. to the above, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use rails built in associations and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```
class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :theme
end
```

Use the [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem to avoid writing all the JS code, examples in HAML, but you should get the point:

*application.js*

```
//= require cocoon
```

Your form:

```
= form_for @theme do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :title
    %br
    = f.text_field :title
  %h3 Options
  #option
    = f.fields_for :options do |option|
      = render 'options_fields', f: option
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add option', f, :options
  = f.submit
```

*_options_fields*:

```
.nested-fields
  .field
    = f.label :name
    %br
    = f.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.label :value
    %br
    = f.text_field :value
  = link_to_remove_association "remove option", f
```

**Question**

Do you want n fields (options) or simply these 3? cocoon is better suited for adding n options.